# How to set thumbnail size in image-dired

Tags: dired, image-mode

I've tried setting `image-dired-thumb-size` (and/or `image-dired-thumb-height` `image-dired-thumb-width`) and it has no effect. I've set it globally in `.emacs` and in various mode-hooks, all to no avail. The default value is 100 and I change it to 256 and the thumbnails are still 100. Inquiring the variables says they are 256.

These variables seem to have no effect. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. It appeared to be broken (changing values had no effect) because image-dired caches its thumbnails in `~/.emacs.d/image-dired/`. Clearing the cache makes the changes effective.

Comment: Just a note for people who might be struggling with the issue of thumb sizes: **it's not sufficient** to just change  `image-dired-thumb-size`, you **also have to change** `image-dired-thumb-height` and `image-dired-thumb-width`!